# Series of consecutive integers

Tags: average

A series of 10584 consecutive integers has a sum that is a perfect cube. What is the smallest possible average of this series?

Answer (score 1):

We are given $$a+(a+1)+...+(a+10583)=x^3$$
$$ (5292)(2a+10583)=x^3$$
Since $5292=3^3(14)^2$ we have $$2a+10583=14y^3$$ 
The above equation has no solution because of parity mismatch of the two sides.

Comment: OP has stated that the integers are consecutive not same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please check the edit

Comment: Yup  , nearly the same result as I got . Only much neater :)